# Find a basis for KerT and ImT (T is a linear transformation)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^5\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ Be a linear transformation such that $T\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z\\ 
t\\ 
w\end{bmatrix}\right)$ = $\begin{bmatrix}
x-2y\\ 
y-2z\\ 
z-2t\\ 
t-2x\end{bmatrix}$

I managed to find the basis and the dimension for $ImT$ pretty easily, however how do I formally prove the dimension and the basis for $KerT$?

Comment: You can, for instance, use the "dimensions. thm", and you have that $5=\dim(Ker) + \dim(Im)$ , so you know which is the dimension of the kernel.

In order to find a basis for the kernel, you just need to solve the linear system $Ax=0$, where $A$ is the representative matrix w.r.t the canonical basis

Answer (score 1):

For the kernel, notice that you must have $x=2y=4z=8t=16x$ so that $x=0$ and from the other equations, $x=y=z=t=0$. It follows that the kernel is $ \{(0,0,0,0,w), w\in\mathbb{R}\}$ so that the kernel is of dimension 1 and a basis is $((0,0,0,0,1))$

Comment: The $\;\ker T\;$ **cannot** be trivial since then $\;T\;$ would be injective, which of course is nonsense.

Comment: Indeed, didn't pay attention to the last variable. Corrected my post, thanks !